# cuda thrust::for_each with thrust::counting_iterator

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm a bit of a newcomer to CUDA and thrust.  I seem to be unable to get the thrust::for_each algorithm to work when supplied with a counting_iterator.
Here is my simple functor:

```
struct print_Functor {
    print_Functor(){}
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(int i)
    {
        printf("index %d\n", i);
    }
};
```

Now if I call this with a host-vector prefilled with a sequence, it works fine:

```
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(10);
    thrust::sequence(h_vec.begin(),h_vec.end());
    thrust::for_each(h_vec.begin(),h_vec.end(), print_Functor());
```

However, if I try to do this with thrust::counting_iterator it fails:

```
    thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(0);
    thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first+10;
    for(thrust::counting_iterator<int> it=first;it!=last;it++)
        printf("Value %d\n", *it);
    printf("Launching for_each\n");
    thrust::for_each(first,last,print_Functor());
```

What I get is that the for loop executes correctly, but the for_each fails with the error message:

```
   after cudaFuncGetAttributes: unspecified launch failure
```

I tried to do this by making the iterator type a template argument:

```
thrust::for_each<thrust::counting_iterator<int>>(first,last, print_Functor());
```

but the same error results.

For completeness, I'm calling this from a MATLAB mex file (64 bit).

I've been able to get other thrust algorithms to work with the counting iterator (e.g. thrust::reduce gives the right result).

As a newcomer I'm probably doing something really stupid and missing something obvious - can anyone help?

Thanks for the comments so far.  I have taken on board the comments so far.  The worked example (outside Matlab) worked correctly and produced output, but if this was made into a mex file it still did not work - the first time producing no output at all and the second time just producing the same error message as before (only fixed by a recompile, when it goes back to no output).

However there is a similar problem with it not executing the functor from thrust::for_each even under DOS.  Here is a complete example:

```
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>

struct sum_Functor {
    int *sum;
    sum_Functor(int *s){sum = s;}
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(int i)
    {
        *sum+=i;
        printf("In functor: i %d sum %d\n",i,*sum);
    }

};

int main(){

    thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(0);
    thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first+10;
    int sum = 0;
    sum_Functor sf(&sum);
    printf("After constructor: value is %d\n", *(sf.sum));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        sf(i);
    }

    printf("Initiating for_each call - current value %d\n", (*(sf.sum)));
    thrust::for_each(first,last,sf);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("After for_each: value is %d\n",*(sf.sum));
}
```

This is compiled under a DOS prompt with:

```
nvcc -o pf pf.cu
```

The output produced is:

```
After constructor: value is 0
In functor: i 0 sum 0
In functor: i 1 sum 1
In functor: i 2 sum 3
In functor: i 3 sum 6
In functor: i 4 sum 10
Initiating for_each call - current value 10
After for_each: value is 10
```

In other words the functor's overloaded operator() is called correctly from the for loop but is never called by the thrust::for_each algorithm.  The only way to get the for_each to execute the functor when using the counting iterator is to omit the member variable.

( I should add that after years of using pure Matlab, my C++ is very rusty, so I could be missing something obvious ...)

Comment: which platform are you on? linux? windows? mac? which CUDA version? which thrust version? which compiler? please always post a [mcve]

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/ebvNdf4v) is a worked (linux non-matlab) example based on what you have shown.  It seems to work correctly for me.   Getting stuff to print from matlab mex may be tricky.

Comment: @m.s - I'm on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit, using the CUDA 7.5 toolkit.  Not sure how to get the thrust version? As supplied with CUDA 7.5.

Comment: @RobertCrovella - thanks for the worked example.  This works correctly when compiled under DOS, but does not under Matlab.  What I get is the first time there is no output at all, and the second time I get full error message: 
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.
What() is:function_attributes(): after cudaFuncGetAttributes: unspecified launch failure
..

Comment: The thrust version given in thrust/version.h indicates I am running 1.8.2

Comment: unspecified launch failure means you made an memory access out of allocated device space. Have you allocated your memory and copied your data using cudaMalloc / CudaMemCpy ?

Comment: as far i know, Matlab stores data in row major, is your kernel expecting column major data?

Comment: @X3liF Matlab is column major, but in this trivial example I don't have any arrays - just scalar (would be 2-d arrays in the final application).   Also - not sure if I'm right here, but this example is executed entirely host-side so should not require cudaMalloc/cudaMemCpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your comments you say that you want your code to be executed on host side.

The error code "unspecified launch failure", and the fact your functor is defined as **host** **device** make me think thrust wants to execute on your device.

Can you add an execution policy to be sure where your code is executed ?

replace :

```
thrust::for_each(first,last,sf);
```

with

```
thrust::for_each(thrust::host, first,last,sf);
```

To be able to run on the GPU, your result must be allocated on device memory (through cudaMalloc) then copied back to host.

---

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

struct sum_Functor {
    int *sum;
    sum_Functor(int *s){sum=s;}
    __host__ __device__
    void operator()(int i)
    {
        atomicAdd(sum, 1);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char**argv){


    thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(0);
    thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first+atoi(argv[1]);
    int *d_sum;
    int h_sum = 0;

    cudaMalloc(&d_sum,sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_sum,&h_sum,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    thrust::for_each(thrust::device,first,last,sum_Functor(d_sum));

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(&h_sum,d_sum,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("sum = %d\n", *h_sum);
    cudaFree(d_sum);

}
```

Code Update : To have the correct result on your device you must use an atomic operation.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that does now give the correct output when you add the thrust::host argument.  Of course in reality I want the code to run on the device, but had simplified it to illustrate the problem!  Looks like I went too far in the simplification.  Will now try it by allocating device memory.

Comment: i've updated your code, i don't like so much a malloc for one int, but the most important, you forgot the AtomicOperation for your int.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update @X3liF - AtomicOperations are something new I have learnt from the exchange - as a newcomer to CUDA there are still areas I need to know about.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: your welcome, don't forget to accept the answer, so the other people will see the solution for your problem.

Comment: not sure what I have to do to "accept" the answer.  I pressed on the "upvote" arrow next to the answer ("The answer is useful") but it said I didn't have enough experience points for the vote to be registered.

Comment: You should see the outline of a check-mark next to this answer.  If you click on that outline to fill it in green, that is how you accept an answer.  You can discover this by looking at the "help" link at the bottom of this page.